# How to Add IF statement in LINQ's WHERE Clause?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var deliverableitems = (from tbl in GetContext.Deliverables.AsEnumerable()
                    where tbl.AutoAuditNotes != Constants.PUBLISH_AUDIT_STRING && tbl.AutoAuditNotes != string.Empty
                    select new CMChangeLogModel
                    {
                        RevisionDateTime = tbl.RevisionDateTime,
                        RevisionUser = tbl.RevisionUser,
                        Note =
                            (
                                tbl.AutoAuditNotes.Contains("Created") ? string.Format("Created Work Product '{0}'", hyperlinktemplate.Replace(pageidtemplate, tbl.DeliverableId.ToString()).Replace(pagetitletemplate, tbl.Title)) :
                                tbl.AutoAuditNotes.Contains("Changed") ? string.Format("Edited Work Product '{0}'", hyperlinktemplate.Replace(pageidtemplate, tbl.DeliverableId.ToString()).Replace(pagetitletemplate, tbl.Title)) :
                                tbl.AutoAuditNotes.Contains("has changed") ? string.Format("Edited Work Product '{0}'", hyperlinktemplate.Replace(pageidtemplate, tbl.DeliverableId.ToString()).Replace(pagetitletemplate, tbl.Title)) :
                                tbl.AutoAuditNotes.Contains("Added") ? string.Format("Edited Work Product '{0}'", hyperlinktemplate.Replace(pageidtemplate, tbl.DeliverableId.ToString()).Replace(pagetitletemplate, tbl.Title)) :
                                tbl.AutoAuditNotes.Contains("Removed") ? string.Format("Edited Work Product '{0}'", hyperlinktemplate.Replace(pageidtemplate, tbl.DeliverableId.ToString()).Replace(pagetitletemplate, tbl.Title)) :
                                tbl.AutoAuditNotes.Contains("Edited") ? string.Format("Edited Work Product '{0}'", hyperlinktemplate.Replace(pageidtemplate, tbl.DeliverableId.ToString()).Replace(pagetitletemplate, tbl.Title)) :
                                tbl.AutoAuditNotes.Contains("Deleted") ? string.Format("Deleted Work Product '{0}'", hyperlinktemplate.Replace(pageidtemplate, tbl.DeliverableId.ToString()).Replace(pagetitletemplate, tbl.Title)) :
                                tbl.AutoAuditNotes.Contains("Restored") ? string.Format("Restored Work Product '{0}'", hyperlinktemplate.Replace(pageidtemplate, tbl.DeliverableId.ToString()).Replace(pagetitletemplate, tbl.Title)) : "Unknown"
                            ),
                        Status = "AuditNote",
                        CM_PageId = tbl.CM_DeliverableId,
                        VMajor = tbl.VMajor,
                        VRevision = tbl.VRevision,
                        PageType = PageTypeEnum.Deliverable.ToString()
                    }).ToList();
```

I have the above code and I have a boolean variable `isLatest_`. If the value of this varaible is true, then I need to add another condition inside the 'where' clause eg : `where tbl.AutoAuditNotes != Constants.PUBLISH_AUDIT_STRING && tbl.AutoAuditNotes != string.Empty && if (isLatest_) { // another condition }` Is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as [HimBromBeere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067786/5528593)'s answer, it can also be achieved like this

```
where tbl.AutoAuditNotes != Constants.PUBLISH_AUDIT_STRING 
    && tbl.AutoAuditNotes != string.Empty 
    && (!isLatest_ || anotherCondition)
```

Maybe someone sees this as more readable, but that's a matter of taste.

The last `&&` part is `true` if `isLatest` is `false` *or* (if `isLatest_` is `true`) depends on `anotherCondition`.

Comment: Cool solution, seems bit more obvious to me +1

Answer (score 1):

Sure, simply use the ternary operator and append `true` if `isLatest_` is `false` also. The `true` ensures that the test passes when all the former conditions pass.

```
where tbl.AutoAuditNotes != Constants.PUBLISH_AUDIT_STRING 
    && tbl.AutoAuditNotes != string.Empty 
    && isLatest_ ? anotherCondition : true
```

Comment: I think you mean `true` - if `isLatest_` is false, the condition shouldn't be applied, so it should be as if it's an "always true" condition.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 0):

**use inline-if:**

```
statement ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse
```

Add to you where : `&& (!isLatest_ ? true : /* Add your condition here */)`

```
from tbl in GetContext.Deliverables.AsEnumerable()
                where tbl.AutoAuditNotes != Constants.PUBLISH_AUDIT_STRING 
&& tbl.AutoAuditNotes != string.Empty 
&& (isLatest_ ? true : /* Add your condition here */)
                    select new CMChangeLogMode
```

Comment: I think you confused it: if `isLatest_` is `true` the `othercondition` should be applied... you return `true` if `isLatest_` is `true` and use the `othercondition` only if `isLatest_` is `false`..